# Statistical formula for counting IF time is greater than

Tags: excel-formula

Your assistance is greatly appreciated with following issue:
Overall goal is two fold

1.) Count the occurances of text "Cannot Analyze QT" only if it is a new occurance. Each row indicates a new time stamp but it should only be counted as a new occurance if the time is >60 seconds from the last row. Not sure if I explained well so I'll give an example, if the text "Cannot Analyze QT" appeared first at 12:01:40, and every minute after until 12:45:40 then I would count as a single occurance (1). If the text showed itself again at 12:51:40 then I would count that as a new occurance and my total so far would be 2.

2.) After having the ability to gather an accurate count for each occurance, I would like to put a duration next to each occurance.

Thank you so much for your assistance. I would have posted a picture or sample date but the site would not allow me to do so.

Kris

Comment: There are hundreds of free file sharing sites out there that will happily let you post files or screenshots. Edit your question and provide links to something to look at, so we can understand the requirements. - If you cannot post a link, just post the URL string. Some people here will know how to make that into a link.

Comment: This looks like homework...

Comment: Hi Taosique, thanks for your comment as it was very helpful in my efforts of counting medical device alarms for goals of better patient safety. Sorry, No, not homework...

Answer (score 0):

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

Column C is just so you can easily see the time difference in seconds from the previous row.

Formula in D2, copied down is

=IF(AND(A3-A2>TIME(0,0,61),B3="Cannot Analyze QT"),1,"")

Formula in E2, copied down is

=SUM(E2,D3)

**Edit after more information provided:**

In your sample spreadsheet, insert a column after column D and use this formula in row 2 of the new column E:

=IF(ISNUMBER(E1),IF(G1=1,D2,E1+D2),0)

This will create a running total of the time since the last new alarm. For a new alarm, the value from the time difference will be returned. For a current alarm, the time difference will be added to the value from the cell above.

The duration can now be pulled out of that column with

=IF(G2=1,E2,"")

[image]

Comment: Hi Teylyn, Thank you so much for the formula. Now looking to get the duration down which would be to SUM the total seconds (duration) from the first row to the last where a count was made (>61). For example (from your screen shot), since we have a count of one in cell D8, we would need to count the seconds (A8-A2). And for the second count in cell D10, we would need to count (D10-D9). Since the row count will always be different I'm assuming the formula will depend on a value in the D column. I hope I've explained correctly. I'll link the file below:

Comment: I added some more formulas to my post.